# Make data in JSON be it's own attribute in Dynamodb?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Whenever I call a post API to my dynamodb, all the data gets store in one "content" attribute. Is there a way to have a separate attribute for each attribute in the JSON structure?

For instance here is where I am calling the API, the JSON structure of data is in the `values` variable.

```
export default (async function submitSite(values) {
  console.log(values);
  createSite(values);
})

function createSite(site) {
  return API.post("sites", "/sites", {
    body: site
  });
}
```

and here is the code for the API itself:

```
export async function main(event, context) {
  const data = JSON.parse(event.body);

  console.log(data);
  var site = "IE"+data.siteCounty+data.siteName;
  var siteIdStripped = site.replace(/[aeiou]/g, '');
  var siteId = siteIdStripped.replace(/ /g,'');
  var siteIdFinal = siteId.toUpperCase();

  const params = {
    TableName: "sites",
    Item: {
      userId: event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId,
      siteId: siteIdFinal,
      content: data,
      createdAt: Date.now()
    }
  };
```

When I upload it is has the structure siteId, userId, content(with an object of data), created at.

Id like for it to be displayed as siteId, userId, siteName, siteAddress, etc etc the last 2 being one of the indexes in the json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are explicitly creating the `content` attribute here: `content: data,`. You either need to explicitly set each attribute like this:

```
Item: {
  userId: event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId,
  siteId: siteIdFinal,
  siteName: data.siteName,
  siteAddress: data.siteAddress,
  createdAt: Date.now()
}
```

Or, you could simplify this with the [object spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) like so:

```
Item: {
  ...data,
  userId: event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId,
  siteId: siteIdFinal,
  createdAt: Date.now()
}
```